# How to make method of subclass inherited from pathlib.Path return Path instead of the subclass

Tags: python, overriding, subclass, super, pathlib

Let's say I have defined a subclass inherited from Path, and I want to use methods from `Path`. For example, `Path.glob()` here:

```
from pathlib import Path


class PhotoDir(Path):
    pass

# some custom methods

if __name__ == "__main__":

    path: str = r"Y:\Picture\2023\2023-11-03"
    photoDir: PhotoDir = PhotoDir(path)

    print(list(photoDir.glob("*")))
```

The result will be:

```
[
PhotoDir('001.jpg'), 
PhotoDir('002.jpg')
]
```

All methods from Path will return the subclass `PhotoDir`.

The result I'm expecting is:

```
[
Path('001.jpg'), 
Path('002.jpg')
]
```

And if I defined another subclass of Path `Photo`, the result should be:

```
[
Photo('001.jpg'), 
Photo('002.jpg')
]
```

### What I have tried

I have tried override methods with `super().glob()`, still the same.(It makes no diff if I'm right.):

```
class PhotoDir(Path):
    def glob(
        self, pattern: str, *, case_sensitive: bool | None = None
    ) -> Generator[Self, None, None]:
        return super().glob(pattern, case_sensitive=case_sensitive)
```

I also tried `Path(self).glob()` in the subclass. This one works, but it seems a little bit incorrect to me.(IDK. Maybe it's right. I'm new to Python)

```
class PhotoDir(Path):
    def glob(
        self, pattern: str, *, case_sensitive: bool | None = None
    ) -> Generator[Self, None, None]:
        return Path(self).glob(pattern, case_sensitive=case_sensitive)
```

Right now I take a work around:

```
class PhotoDir:
    def __init__(self, *args: str | PathLike[str]) -> None:
        self.path: Path = Path(*args)
```

I didn't subclassing Path at all. Instead of using `photoDir.glob()`, I'm using `photoDir.path.glob()`. It works fine, but is there a smarter way to do this in Python?

Comment: Is there a reason you need plain `Path` objects instead of `PhotoDir` objects? If you are subclassing correctly, then an instance of `PhotoDir` should be usable *anywhere* an instance of `Path` is expected.

Comment: For example, `PhotoDir.glob()` returns `PhotoDir('001.jpg')`, which is not a dir at all. There are some operations in `PhotoDir.__init__()` that should not be applied to it.

Comment: Then your semantics don't allow for subclassing, as a `Path` represents a path to *any* file-system entry, not just directories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `PhotoDir` class doesn't represent an arbitrary file path, so subclassing isn't appropriate. It represents a *directory*, one attribute of which is the file path that identifies it, so your final example of composition is the appropriate solution.

```
class PhotoDir:
    def __init__(self, *args: str | PathLike[str]) -> None:
        self.path: Path = Path(*args)

    def glob(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.path.glob(*args, **kwargs)
```